# AngularJS reloading multiple tab in the same time if any change

Tags: angularjs

I have an add form that if the user file the form and submit, in the same time, user can see the data in the same page in table with ui-view and this is not an issue!!

Problem is: if i open more than one tab in the same browser, that post or change reflection doesn't show in other tab without refreshing or reloading. i want to see change in other tab of browser or other browser without reload

I want to see the change without refresh or reloading. 
if i reload in other tab, it works but if i dont reload in other tab, the change doesn't effect

here you go for my post method:

```
$scope.formModel = {}; 
  $scope.onSubmit = function () {
      $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/create/', $scope.formModel)
      .then(function(response) { //if success, below fuction will execute
        $scope.successPost = 'You have successfully submitted your Contact';
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.successPost = '';
        }, 4000);
        //below $scope will push data in client site if the request is success
        $scope.contacts.push(response.data);
        //if any error occurs, below function will execute
      }, function(response) {
        // below variable will get predefined message that will explain exactly what happened
        var errorData = response.data;
        $scope.errorPost = Object.values(errorData)[0][0];
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.errorPost = '';
        }, 4000);
      });
      $scope.formModel = {}; //It means, after submit, the form field will clear
      $scope.addContactForm.$setPristine(); 
  };
```

I want to see the change in the other tab without refresh or reload

Comment: Have a read here:  https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/keeping-browser-tabs-in-sync-using-localstorage-ngrx-and-rxjs-87de3bca4e2c    (It uses Angular v8+, rather than AngularJS though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well browser tabs are per definition separated from each other and can't communicate directly between each other.
there are certain possibilities to handle that: for example you can have a separate external service and always poll that service for latest changes and if something changes automatically call reload.

or you could use a service that provide a websocket that sends you to the frontend an update notification once something changed in your data.

Just want to point you in the right direction, the topic is to big to provide a finished solution. I recommend to do some research on how to communicate between tabs / how to build a service with an update notification for new data

Edit: Just to add @Yftach point from the comments: Theoretically localstorage is shared between tabs, so theoretically you could have a variable there and watch in an interval for changes. However the solution with a separate server is (at least in my eyes) way better

Comment: Thanks for great suggestion

Comment: For the record localstorage is shared between tabs. But usually  you're right, you would want to handle that communication through a server.

Comment: @Yftach yeah thats actually true, but does not sound like good practice (at least to me) to share a variable through local storage and watch for changes